# How to make git check for fetch and then make picture or sound?

Tags: git

How to make git check for fetch and then make picture or sound?
Want to have notification without fetching all the time all

Comment: "without fetching all the time all" ... all what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can create a new [`git` alias](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases):

```
git config --global alias.f '!git fetch && [ $(git rev-parse HEAD) != $(git rev-parse @{u}) ] && notify-send "Updates found"'
```

This creates a new alias `f` which runs:

```
git fetch &&
  [ $(git rev-parse HEAD) != $(git rev-parse @{u}) ] &&
  notify-send "Updates found"
```

The middle line checks if [the current branch and its remote are on the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17938274/2072269), and if not, uses `notify-send` to send a notification.

Now if you run `git f` in a branch with remote updates, you'll get a notification.